# Extended django user profile data overwrite issue

Tags: django, user-profile

I create an userprofile as following:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required:
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="User can view study permission")  
    # Other fields:
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    disease = models.ManyToManyField(Disease) 
    date_assigned = models.DateTimeField("Date Assigned")
    query = models.ManyToManyField(Query, blank=True) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        studies = ', '.join(study.name for study in self.disease.all())
        return "%s can view %s" % (self.user, studies)
```

It's extended information for users.
Now I am creating a admin page by myself to allow the admin to update the users account information which included the above user profile.
The form and code for this is as following:

```
def edit(request, user_id):
"""Edit a user's details"""
try:
  user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
except User.DoesNotExist:
  user = None

# user exists:    
if user:
# Initial form field data:
  initial={'user_id': user_id,
         'username': user.username,
         'fname': user.first_name,
         'lname': user.last_name,
         'email': user.email,
         'phone': user.get_profile().phone,
         'groups': user.groups.all(),
         'studies': user.get_profile().disease.all(),
         'is_admin': user.is_staff,
         'is_active': user.is_active
         }

request.breadcrumbs(
  (_("Home"), reverse('home')),
  (_("All Users"), reverse('all users')),
  (_("User Details"), reverse('user details', args=[user_id])), 
)

if request.method == "GET":
  form = UserProfileEditForm(initial=initial,extra=request.user.id)
  response = {'heading': 'Edit', 'form': form}
  return render_to_response('accounts/edit.html',
                            response,
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                            )
elif request.method == "POST":
  form = UserProfileEditForm(request.POST,extra=request.user.id)
  if form.is_valid():
    Log().add(request, "Edit", "W", "userprofile", user_id)

    if form.cleaned_data['password1'] and form.cleaned_data['password2']:
      user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
    user.username = form.cleaned_data['username']
    user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['fname']
    user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['lname']
    user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    user.groups = form.cleaned_data['groups']
    user.is_staff = form.cleaned_data['is_admin']
    user.is_active = form.cleaned_data['is_active']
    user.save()

    # Oddly to make the extra fields found in UserProfile are saved, you
    # have to call get_profile().ATTRIBUTE, assign a value, then call
    # get_profile().save(). Calling user.save() as the last step won't 
    # save any changes made to UserProfile:
    disease_pks = form.cleaned_data['studies']
    user.get_profile().disease = Disease.objects.filter(pk__in=disease_pks)
    user.get_profile().phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
    user.get_profile().save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/view/%s" % user_id)
  else:
    # form is not valid:
    return render_to_response("accounts/edit.html",
                              {'form': form, 'heading': 'Edit'},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                              )
# user does not exist:
else:
  error = "User #%s cannot be found. Press the 'BACK' button on your browser." % user_id 
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('DigitalRecords.views.error', args=(error,)))

class UserProfileEditForm(forms.Form):
user_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"))
password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), 
                          widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
                          required=False
                          )
password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password (again)"), 
                          widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
                          required=False
                          )  
fname = forms.CharField(label=_("First name"))
lname = forms.CharField(label=_("Last name"))
email = forms.EmailField()
phone = forms.CharField(label=_("Phone"))
is_admin = forms.BooleanField(label=_("Is an administrator?"), required=False)
is_active = forms.BooleanField(label=_("Is an active user?"), required=False)
groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(),
                                      widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
                                      )
#Attach a form helper to this class
helper = FormHelper()
helper.form_id = "edituserprofile"
helper.form_class = "userprofile"

#Add in a submit and reset button
submit = Submit("Save", "Save Changes")
helper.add_input(submit)
reset = Reset("Reset", "Reset")
helper.add_input(reset)

def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
  extra = kwargs.pop('extra')
  super(UserProfileEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  self.fields["studies"] =        forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.get(id=extra).get_profile().disease.all(),
                                       widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
                                       ) 

def clean_username(self):
  """Check if the username does not already exist"""
  username = self.cleaned_data['username']
  user_id = self.cleaned_data['user_id']

  # handle:
  try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
  except User.DoesNotExist:
    return self.cleaned_data['username']
  else:
    if user.id == user_id:
      return self.cleaned_data['username']
    else:  
      raise forms.ValidationError('User "%s" already exists' % username)

def clean_fname(self):

  fname = self.cleaned_data['fname']
  # Remove any diacritics/accented characters:
  fname = strip_diacritic(fname).strip()
  # Match names that may have hyphens, apostrophes, or periods in them.
  # example: John Doe, O'Brien, Leroy-Brown, Cpt. James T. Kirk
  pattern = '^([a-zA-Z]+(?:\.)?(?:[\-\' ][a-zA-Z]+(?:\.)?)*)$'

  # match the regex to the input string.
  results = re.match(pattern, str(fname))

  if results == None:
    raise ValidationError(u'%s is not a valid name' % fname)
  return fname

def clean_lname(self):
  """
  Determine if the patient's name is valid. It removed any accented/diacritic 
  characters and replaces them with the base character for simplicity. Names with 
  hyphens and/ore apostrophes like Hanna-Barbara and O'Brien are allowed. If the 
  check fails a validation error is raised.
  """ 
  lname = self.cleaned_data['lname']    
  # Remove any diacritics/accented characters:
  lname = strip_diacritic(lname).strip()    
  # Match names that may have hyphens, apostrophes, or periods in them.
  # example: John Doe, O'Brien, Leroy-Brown, Cpt. James T. Kirk
  pattern = '^([a-zA-Z]+(?:\.)?(?:[\-\' ][a-zA-Z]+(?:\.)?)*)$'

  # match the regex to the input string.
  results = re.match(pattern, str(lname))

  if results == None:
    raise ValidationError(u'%s is not a valid name' % lname)
  return lname

def clean(self):
  """Check if password1 and password2 match"""
  cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
  password1 = cleaned_data.get('password1')
  password2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')

  # Notice it's an 'or' condition because a password change is optional:
  if password1 or password2:
    if password1 != password2:
      msg = "Passwords do not match"
      self._errors['password1'] = self.error_class([msg])
      self._errors['password2'] = self.error_class([msg])
      del cleaned_data['password1']
      del cleaned_data['password2']
      return cleaned_data
  return self.cleaned_data
```

It works fine if an administrator trying to edit other user's account information.
However, when an administrator tried to update his own account. The disease field will always be blank whatever this field was changed or not.

Does anyone the reason and how should I change my code?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about other code, but these lines in your view does not seem appropriate.

```
user.get_profile().disease = Disease.objects.filter(pk__in=disease_pks)
user.get_profile().phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
user.get_profile().save()
```

You are getting new profile object each time by calling `user.get_profile()` and updating it. Not saving it, instead a new object. So change it to

```
profile = user.get_profile()
profile.disease = Disease.objects.filter(pk__in=disease_pks)
profile.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
profile.save()
```

Comment: I tried to update the codes as you suggested. However, the problem still exist. Disease field is always blank after an admin try to save the updates of his own account.